# how do resteasy encryption using s/mime

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

i have to encrypt json data using s/mime.

i go through the these links:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/ch38.html

while i am doing according to above mention link but i am unable to encrypt that 
here is my code:

```
 @Path("encrypted")
     @GET
      @Produces("text/plain")

      @GZIP
      public EnvelopedOutput getAllOpenMeetings(@QueryParam("batchsize")
      int batchSize, @QueryParam("offset")
      int offset, @Context
      HttpServletRequest req) {

        String ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr();


        EnvelopedOutput output=null;
        CustomerBean bean=null;
        try {
           bean=new CustomerBean();
          bean.setDesc("abc");
          bean.setName("xyz");

          //certificate generation
          FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("e:/arruun/keystore.jks"); 
//        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
                KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
//        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
                store.load(stream, "password".toCharArray());

                PrivateKey      key = (PrivateKey)store.getKey(
                                                 "selfsigned", "password".toCharArray());

                Certificate[]   chain = store.getCertificateChain(
                        "selfsigned");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[0];


          X509V3Generator generator=new X509V3Generator();

           output = new EnvelopedOutput(bean, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

          output.setCertificate(cert);
          return output;

        }  
        catch (Exception ex) {

            String result = "Error 500 - Internal Server Error";
            System.out.println("exception=="+ex.getMessage());
            return null;
//       
        }


      }
```

So please can anyone provide a small example of resteasy encryption(i.e json body encryption using s/mime)

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to encrypt?"  Do you receive an exception?

Comment: yeah got this exception: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.util.EnvelopedOutput["certificate"]->sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl["publicKey"]->sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl["algorithmId"]->sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId["oid"]) ,can you tell where is the problem?